# Copy/Paste from Python command line to sublime

Tags: python, keyboard, copy, sublimetext3, paste

Apologies in advance for what should seem obvious to me...

New to Python, but other wise very experience, hence the frustration.

As I'm learning, I'm attempting to prototype the command at the command prompt (">>>") as I script.  I can enter the python commands and validate they are correct, but (currently) then have to retype the command in to sublime, which seems inane, especially as I'm watching videos where they are copying and pasting one to the other...

[Windows 7 CMD, & Python ">>>" command lines, Sublime window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8fVc.png)

I'm trying to copy commands from the Python command line ">>>" to the sublime editor in an open/new tab.  Normally, I would mark/highlight the selection, then Ctrl+c, place the cursor in the target window (sublime in this case), Ctrl-v, and be done.

However, I'm unable to select what I want to copy (??).  Up/down arrows will recall the individual lines (no problem with that) -- where I would usually do a Ctrl-(left/right arrow) to select the text, but no indication that anything has been selected.  Same result using the mouse.

Thanks in advance for the assist.

Comment: Which OS is this? Different OS use different ways of copying text from the terminal/command window. Do you have a mouse as well? Or only keyboard?

Comment: thanks for the quick response...Win 7, mouse yes.

Comment: A screenshot of your display would help, as I don't know if you are using integrated terminal in sublime or a separate window. For windows terminal you usually have to use the shift key and mouse to highlight what you want, and the then rightclick and copy.

Comment: FYI Shift+keyboard, Shift & Mouse - No joy

Comment: THAT WAS IT @G5W !

Thanks for all the help, everyone -- hope to return the favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oddity of the Windows command prompt. First, there is a little bit of setup. Then you can do the cut-and-paste in a slightly different way than you are used to.

**Setup** 
Right click on the title bar at the top. Select "Properties". Click on the "Options" tab. Make sure that the "QuickEditMode" box is checked. Close the Properties window.

Cut-and-paste should be enabled, but not using control-C to cut. Select the text you want to copy. Instead of typing control-C, just hit return (with the desired text selected). The text should now be on the clipboard to paste into other applications (with control-V)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux terminals, pressing Ctrl+k copies everything in the line that follows the cursor. Ctrl+u copies the everything before the cursor.